# angularJS x-editable status based condition

Tags: jquery, css, angularjs

I have implemented some color classes so that the status changes the color of the `tr`

```
<tr id="item" class="tRow" ng-class="{'status1':'red', 'status2:'green', 'status3:'yellow'}[item.status]" ng-repeat="item in items | filter:search | filter:{section_id:filter.section_id} |orderBy:orderByFilter:reverse | limitTo:limit" ng-show="checkPriceFilter(item.price)">
```

Now I want to change "`section_id`" when `status2` is active for more then a day or so

I tried something in `jquery` but it didnt work.. I want the `angular` way.

```
$('#mainDiv tr').each(function()
{
  if ($(this).hasClass('green')) {
      //function
     }
});
```

Comment: It's better not to mix Angular and jQuery like this.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by `when status2 is active for more then a day or so`? Is it based on some kind of date variable or?

Comment: @dfsq OP mentions in the question that he wants to use AngularJS but this is what he tried in jQuery.

Comment: @peter yes it will be based on some date variable or counter..haven't done it yet. suggestions are welcome. first i am trying to grab my tr's classes to give it a condition..

Comment: I think I kind of get what you're trying to accomplish but it's hard to figure it out without any code. I suggest you try to make something that shows the purpose and add that to your question.